# Changing multiple images source using jquery (and some other thing as well)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner of javascript and jquery and i have 11 image tags in html. I want to 
basically change sources of these tags using js and jquery. This code is not working and I am not getting any errors in firebug, can some one please tell me where I am doing wrong?

```
var imagesArray2=["01.png","02.png","03.png","04.png","05.png","06.png","07.png","08.png","09.png","10.png","11.png"];
var elementArray2 = ["#img1","#img2","#img3","#img4","#img5","#img6","#img7","#img8","#img9","#img10","#img11"];
var imagesArray,elementArray;
var elementInArray;
```

document ready

```
$(function(){
setInterval(Myfunction(),1000);});
```

my function code which has a loop based on `elementsInArray` variable value and it calls `imageFadeAnimations` function

```
function Myfunction(){
    if(elementsInArray === 0){
       imagesArray = imagesArray2;
       elementArray = elementArray2;
       elementsInArray = elementArray.length;
       var imageChanges = Math.floor(Math.random()*elementsInArray);
       imageFadeAnimations(imageChanges);
    }
    else
    {
        elementsInArray=elementArray.length;
        imageChanges = Math.floor(Math.random()*elementsInArray);
        imageFadeAnimations(imageChanges);
    }
}
```

takes an integer as argument

```
function imageFadeAnimations(imageChanges){
    for(var k = 0;k<imageChanges;k++){
        var element = Math.floor(Math.random()*elementsinArray);
        var image=Math.floor(Math.random()*elementsinArray);
        imageChanger(elementArray[element],imageArray[image]);
        elementArray.splice(element,1);
        imagesArray.splice(image,1);
    }
}
function imageChanger(b1,b2){
    $(b1).fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(b1).attr("src",b2);
        $(b1).fadeIn(500);
    });
}
```

Comment: Change `setInterval(Myfunction(),1000);});` to `setInterval(Myfunction,1000);});`

Comment: yes did that , but the problem with this code is , it never goes into imageChanger function

Comment: You have declared a variable elementInArray and then you call for a variable elementsInArray. Can you make a fiddle with your code? :)

Comment: Do you realise that javascript objects (including arrays) are assigned by reference, not by value, so `imagesArray = imagesArray2;` just creates a reference to the *same* array? Also, `.splice();` returns a new array containing any removed elements, without affecting the original array, therefore calling `.splice()` and doing nothing with the returned array, will have zero affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making heavy weather out of something that jQuery can make very simple.

First wrap your images in an element (typically a div or a span) with `id="imageContainer"`.

Now, if I understand correctly, your code will simplify to :

```
$(function() {
    var imagesArray = ["01.png", "02.png", "03.png", "04.png", "05.png", "06.png", "07.png", "08.png", "09.png", "10.png", "11.png"],
        $images = $("img", "#imageContainer");

    setInterval(function() {
        $images.each(function() {
            var $img = $(this),
                i = Math.min(imagesArray.length-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length));
            $img.fadeOut().promise().then(function() {
                $img.attr("src", imagesArray[i]).fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

**EDIT 1**

As @mplungjan points out below ...

If the img nodes were initialised with `src` attributes, then `imagesArray` can be composed by grabbing the srcs from the DOM as follows (replacing two lines above) :

```
    var $images = $("img", "#imageContainer"),
        imagesArray = $images.map(function() { return this.src; }).get();
```

Comment: The imageArray would be even better grabbed from the src of the  $("img", "#imageContainer");

Comment: Nice one @mplungjan :) Added as EDIT 1 above.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this jquery/zepto code is not the smaller, but the easier to understand:

```
function changeImg(){ 
$("#img1").attr('src', '01.png');
$("#img2").attr('src', '02.png');       
$("#img3").attr('src', '03.png');
$("#img4").attr('src', '04.png');
$("#img5").attr('src', '05.png');       
$("#img6").attr('src', '06.png');                           
};
```